# How to display location on a map

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to display users location on world map using html, javascript or any other way, while the data will be pulled from exel file. 
The location data is basicly a City Name, and i want to show it on world map as mark/dot for each user.

the map need to be displayed on a website and update every time user refresh the site.

is there a way it can be done?
if someone have something like this it will be very appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display location Using Longitude/Latitude Coordinates - Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135722/display-location-using-longitude-latitude-coordinates-google-maps)

Answer (score 1):

The most common way these days is to use [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) they have a lot of [sample code here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)

Alternatives to google maps can be found here [Open alternatives to Google-maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561120/open-alternatives-to-google-maps)

You will most likely need to learn a server side language that can read the spreadsheet data and pass it to the frontend. Solutions for this exist in PHP, ruby, node.js, asp etc...

Answer (score 0):

What about using OpenLayers , here is a full example :

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>OpenLayers Demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  html, body, #basicMap {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
  }
 </style>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="basicMap"></div>

<script>
 init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
function init() {
map = new OpenLayers.Map("basicMap", {
    controls: [
               new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
               new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
               new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
           ]
       });
var mapnik         = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
var position       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(7.55785346031189,50.3625329673905).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
var zoom           = 3

map.addLayer(mapnik);
map.setCenter(position, zoom );

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);

var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position);

marker.events.register("click", map , function(e){ alert("click");
});

markers.addMarker(marker);
}
```

Please note that this is just a sample, and markers are deprecated.

For further informations , look http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers-js.html

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use Google Maps you can load your Excel data into a Google Spreadsheet. The locations can then be mapped directly on Google Maps from the spreadsheet. Have a look at this [demo](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without writing code, check out [GeoSheets](http://www.geosheets.com) to create the map directly from your spreadsheet.  GeoSheets is a free add-on for Google Sheets that makes it super easy to create customized and embeddable maps.