# Google Maps API Alternatives?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

Starting June 11, 2018: All Gogle Maps Platform API requests must include an API key; we no longer support keyless access. I heard that the gogle maps api-key is not free. Does anyone know any free alternatives it?
I am student.I need a map api and I don't have eneugh money.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative Map API's (Like Google Maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609344/alternative-map-apis-like-google-maps)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open alternatives to Google-maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561120/open-alternatives-to-google-maps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative Map API's (Like Google Maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609344/alternative-map-apis-like-google-maps)

Answer (score -2):

I've used openstreetmap.org for a few projects, works well. That being said... a small project using the google api will usually not generate enough traffic to warrant any costs, as you're given a certain amount of traffic for free every month.