# comparison between openlayers.org and mapstraction.com

Tags: gis, openlayers, mapstraction

I just handed new GIS project and given two choices for map solution.

1. http://mapstraction.com
2. http://openlayers.org

Now i know only google maps and dont have any idea about the above two.
My goal is to provide price effective solution (thats main) having good performance and doing basic task on map like display points, draw region (polygons), create markers.

I also had to do geocoding and reverse geo coding but from my search i dont think its possible with the above two, but i can get third party vendor here to do it.

Guys i need your feedback here badly.

Thank you

Comment: got some help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237187/openlayers-vs-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

Mapstraction isn't a library in it's own right, it's an abstraction layer that allows you to write your map code once and then swap from say OpenLayers to Google Maps (or about 12 other providers) by changing one line of JavaScript code.

Mapstraction also provides a geocoding abstraction currently supports seven geocoding providers including Google and OpenLayers.

Check out the [Mapstraction wiki](https://github.com/mapstraction/mxn/wiki) for more details.

Alternatively you can use [OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html) directly for mapping and geocoding via [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).